# Time for a particular object Date

Tags: java, android, date, alarmmanager

Is there any method en Date or Calendar class to know the milliseconds remaining from the time of the query to a particular Date object?

I'm using Alarmmanager for reschedule the alarms and would be important for me.

The solucion that I have at the moment is get the milliseconds of the existing object and deduct the current milliseconds.

Any better solution?

Thanks!

Comment: So, you want the difference in milliseconds between two Date objects?

Comment: yes, it's a possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want how many milliseconds two `Date` values differ by, that's really easy using [`Date.getTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29):

```
long millisLeft = target.getTime() - now.getTime();
```

Comment: But... Exists any method like the following... long milis (Date objectDate) that return the milliseconds to objectDate?

Comment: @HéctorOrtiz: From the current time? No, but it's a one-line method to write yourself... just substitute `System.currentTimeMillis()` for `now.getTime()` above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Just use the Calenda, This class can give you time in miiliseconds (if that is what you want. So in your case you can just subtract two seperate Calanders. by the way you might also must likly nalso need  GregorianCalendar;

ie that is

```
 Calendar timeStamp = new GregorianCalendar();
```

hope this helps
you can also see one of my projects that uses this at 
http://be.net/HARO

see the progague project in java, mostly used in the device,state device, numerical device classes.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
ChronoUnit.MILLISECONDS.between(       // This enum object offers a method for calculated elapsed time in a particular granularity.
    myJavaUtilDateStart.toInstant() ,  // Convert from legacy class (`java.util.Date`) to modern class (`java.time.Instant`).
    myJavaUtilDateStop.toInstant()
)                                      // Returns a long integer.
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

### `Instant`

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction). This class replaces `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture current moment in UTC in up to nanosecond resolution.
```

### `ChronoUnit.MILLISECONDS`

To calculate elapsed time as a count of milliseconds specifically, use `ChronoUnit.MILLISECONDS` enum object. Beware of data loss, as any microseconds or nanoseconds in the `Instant` objects will be ignored.

```
long millisElapsed = ChronoUnit.MILLISECONDS.between( startInstant , stopInstant ) ;
```

### `Duration`

Java offers a couple classes for represent a span of time unattached to the timeline:

- `Period` for years-months-days.
- `Duration` for hours-minutes-seconds-fractionalSecond.

Example:

```
Duration d = Duration.between( startInstant , stopInstant ) ;
```

Generate a String in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format by calling `Duration::toString`.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).